# Copiando informações do imdb

Tags: php, libcurl

Boa madrugada a todos , bom estou criando uma aplicação em  a PHP e necessito pegar informações de filmes do IMDb ,Qual melhor forma de captura as informações do IMDb? Curl ou existe algum api que mim ajude nisso?

Comment: Divirta-se: http://www.imdb.com/interfaces

Comment: @Sorack obrigado amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa decodificar a resposta e atribuí-la a variáveis ​​(tudo em PHP).

```
<?php
$id = $_POST["id"];
$url = file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=$id");
$json = json_decode($url, true); //This will convert it to an array
$movie_title = $json['Title'];
$movie_year = $json['Year'];
//and so on...
```

e então quando você precisa ecoá-los:

```
echo $movie_title;
```

ou

```
echo "The movie '$movie_title' was made in $movie_year.";
```

Pode usar esse também: [PHP-IMDB-API](https://github.com/yswery/PHP-IMDB-API) é em json.

Comment: Cara era exatamente isso que eu buscava, muito obrigado msm

Comment: @CarlosdaSilva Coloquei um link de um projeto que tem no github, da uma olhada, talvez também ajude.

Comment: Ok, fiz o pedido do apikey que é necessário para o funcionamento do omdbapi, estou aguardando o recebimento do msm

Comment: Pois irei traduzir com o próprio PHP algumas coisas usando uma biblioteca do Google Translator tais como sinopse para logo após salvar no banco de dados

Comment: @CarlosdaSilva no arquivo imdbapi.class.php tem como alterar o idioma, mas apenas troca os gêneros.

Comment: é realmente um projeto bacana, posso está utilizando e  fazendo melhorias no projeto. Vou ver qual melhor opção.